# How to handle thrown exception in NUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I have written a unit test class in C# for my MVC project.

The Test Method is following

```
 [Test]
    public void To_Add_DocumentStatusIsNull_ThrowsInvalidOperationException_ServiceTest()
    {
        try
        {

        _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock = new Mock<IDocumentStatusRepository>();
        _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

        DocumentStatusService documentStatusService = new  
         DocumentStatusService(_unitOfWorkMock.Object,  
          _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock.Object); 

        DocumentStatus documentStatus;
        documentStatus = null;

        _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Add(documentStatus));
        documentStatusService.Add(documentStatus);

        Assert.Pass();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the Service Method is following

```
   public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        _repository.Add(entity);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now This test method only not passed due to the service class thrown ArgumentNullException.So how to handle the ArgumentNullException or How to make this test pass?

Please anybody help

Comment: what is the purpose of `throw new Exception(e.Message);` in your service method? why don't you just let the original exception be raised? I can't see any use for that `try`/`catch` setup...? And there's *certainly* no point in the `try`/`catch` in the NUnit test shown - NUnit automatically treats exceptions as errors, unless you have indicated a known expected exception

Comment: Sorry, That is written for some other purpose and You are right this is incorrect.Now i want to know how to handle the ArgumentNullException in my test method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to check that the `ArgumentNullException` is working (which: it isn't currently). then it sounds like you want:

```
[Test, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException), ExpectedMessage = @"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity")]
public void To_Add_DocumentStatusIsNull_ThrowsInvalidOperationException_ServiceTest()
{
    _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock = new Mock<IDocumentStatusRepository>();
    _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

    DocumentStatusService documentStatusService = new  
     DocumentStatusService(_unitOfWorkMock.Object,  
      _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock.Object); 

    DocumentStatus documentStatus;
    documentStatus = null;

    _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Add(documentStatus));
    documentStatusService.Add(documentStatus);
}
```

...

```
public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    }
    _repository.Add(entity);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code such that is given above but there is no changes made

Comment: This is not a correct answer, because, I want to be able to differentiate bugs in NUnit Framework 3 from bugs in the code I am testing. How would I go about catching NUnit Framework bugs, which I keep running into, and marking the test appropriately?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn just because you want to do something different doesn't mean this answer is wrong; but: you could perhaps catch `NUnitException` or whatever it is that gets thrown and handle that separately? although really, unless you're actually debugging nunit, I don't see how this is a real problem to be solved

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I checked the NUnit code, but it does not contain an NUnitException. It relies on standard exception classes, which means differentiating can be difficult. I shouldn't fail a test just because NUnit has a bug.

Comment: I was wrong! I did find NUnitException in the Github project for NUnit. I'll check for NUnitExceptions from now on. Then I can mark my tests as "Blocked" or "Not Run"

Answer (score 3):

**Testing for the ArgumentNullException**

If you remove the ill-advised

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

from your code to be tested (The current `catch` loses context of the error, and breaks the stack trace, see below), your test can be as simple as wrapping the invocation in an `Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>()`:

```
[Test]
public void PassingANullEntityToAddMustThrowArgumentNullException()
{
    var documentStatusService = new  DocumentStatusService(...); 
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>  documentStatusService.Add(null));
}
```

**Re: Your Exception Handler**

In your service code, never catch an exception and rethrow it as you've done, as this will lose the stack trace (e.g. `_repository.Add(entity);` could throw as well.). You also aren't adding any value by throwing `e.Message` as this is already in the original exception (with additional info like stack trace and inner exception)

Bad:

```
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      throw new Exception(e.Message);
  }
```

Better: If you do catch and rethrow with some value, wrap the original as an inner exception:

```
 catch (SqlException ex)
 {
    throw new Exception("Some value add here", ex);
 }
```

or if you are just intercepting and allow to propagate:

```
 catch (SqlException)
 {
    // Do some logging
    throw;
 }
```

Best to me would to let the exception propagate, unless you either adding value, or handling it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming: Looking at the code this unit test should not pass. Adding a NULL to a list is in most cases not an intended behaviour.

I see 2 options:
A) You should add a try/catch to you Test metod.

```
try 
{
    _IDocumentStatusRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Add(documentStatus));
    documentStatusService.Add(documentStatus);
}
catch (Exception )
{
    Assert.Fail(); // or nothing is expected behaviour
}
```

B) Remove the try/catch block from the Test Method so you do not swallow the exception. (Every Test that does not fails or an Assert or thows an unhandeled exception automatically passes)

Comment: Yes, this unit test should not pass, But I don't know to behave it. And I tried your solutions such that is given above, there is nothing changed.Please any other solution?